# Can we derive type 2 error probability from confidence interval?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, p-value, type-i-and-ii-errors

If we can compute confidence intervals for an estimate $\hat{\theta}$, [then we can also compute the *p* value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/561578/34792) for an [associated hypothesis $\theta=\theta_0$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351320/can-we-reject-a-null-hypothesis-with-confidence-intervals-produced-via-sampling), which is the probability of a type 1 error (i.e., rejecting the hypothesis when it is correct) for a particular sample.

Can we also use those confidence intervals to get at the probability of a type 2 error for that hypothesis and sample (i.e., accepting the hypothesis when it is not correct)?

Intuitively it seems like we should be able to, because a narrower confidence interval *seems* directly proportional to a more powerful test, which is (by definition) a lower type 2 error probability.  And because a type 2 error *seems* like the complement of {no error} + {type 1 error}.  (But if these *seemings* are incorrect an explanation of that might also help.)

Comment: Why would you want to compute statistical power after your data has been collected? The comments and answer of this other thread may interest you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579152/post-hoc-power-analysis-for-null-results-how-to-use-95-confidence-interval-ins

Comment: First, you must not write $\hat\theta=\theta_0$, but $\theta=\theta_0$, because the hypothesis is always about the true parameter and not the estimate. "True parameter" is also the key word for why that will not be possible, because the type II error probability will depend on the true parameter (the further away it is from the null, the higher the power) which we do not know just from computing the confidence interval (or from anything really, which is why we do inference in the first place).

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks; I just fixed the notation.  Meanwhile, I'm not immediately able to understand why we can compute both type 1 error probability of a sample, and type 2 error probability of a test (power), but not type 2 error probability in a specific experiment.

Comment: Maybe an example like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203090/power-calculations-uniform0-theta/203181#203181 helps - the power *function* depends on, there too, $\theta$, and we do not know which $\theta$ to plug in based on your experiment. You *could* pick $\hat\theta$, but since (this is the whole point of looking at tests and c.i.s, after all) this estimator has sampling variability, it would not be correct to claim that you have the computed power in an experiement like the one you have conducted.

Comment: @feetwet To add to Christoph's comments, generally, power analysis is conducted before an experiment, to find the required sample size necessary to detect a given effect size with a pre-determined power. So it's unclear why you'd want to conduct power analysis *after* an experiment, post-hoc power analysis being essentially redundant (you may find several questions and answers about it on this website). I suspect that the confusion your express in comments might come from that. If you explain why you want to conduct post-hoc power analysis, it could help to give you a relevant answer.

Comment: @J-J-J I don't think I'm asking about power analysis per se.  Rather, I want to see if, having conducted an experiment, we can say anything else about errors other than, "Here's the odds of a type 1 error in this particular experiment" (p-value) and here is a range that contains the true value with some probability (CI).  I edited the question to note that it seems like a type 2 error would be the complement of a type 1 error + no error.  Can't we say something about the odds of a type 2 error in the experiment outcome?  Or are we limited to statements about type 1 errors?

Comment: and here is a range that contains the true value with some *confidence*.