# What is this distribution called?

Tags: distributions, density-function, terminology

For every positive integer $n$,
$nx^{n-1}$
is a probability density function in $[0,1]$. What is it called?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18433/how-do-you-calculate-the-probability-density-function-of-the-maximum-of-a-sample

Comment: Thanks. So it is a Beta distribution with $\alpha=n$ and $\beta=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distribution with pdf

$$
f(x) = \frac{\beta x^{\beta-1}}{\alpha^\beta}
$$

is known as the ["power distribution"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerDistribution.html) (unfortunately, it’s a very google-unfriendly name). It is alternatively parametrized by $k = 1/\alpha$. It has the $(0, \alpha]$ support.

Comment: I think the version here on $[0,1]$ is a ["standard power function distribution"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Beta_distribution#The_name_of_a_special_case?)