# Why do we need Gumbel distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, gumbel-distribution

I check the [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%20and%20statistics,of%20samples%20of%20various%20distributions.&text=This%20article%20uses%20the%20Gumbel,distribution%20of%20the%20maximum%20value.) article on Wikipedia, it says it is useful to represent the distribution of maxima. But it is not easy to understand how it works? A detailed explanation or examples may be more helpful.

I notice the pdf of the distribution is very close to the exponential distribution, $e^{-(z + e^{-z})}$ compared with $e^{-z}$? I believe the extra term could bring some useful properties, but I do know its concrete advantages, a close-form cdf?

Comment: The right tail of a Gumbel distribution is similar to that of an exponential distribution, but the left side is very different, with a positive density for all negative reals.  Another point is that the location can easily be shifted (which is why you are seeing $z$ rather than $x$)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a sample of iid $\{ X_1, ..., X_n \}$, we can compute its maximum $Y = \max \{ X_1, ..., X_n \}$. The question is, if the values of the sample follow a distribution $P(X)$, what is the distribution for the maximum value of the sample, $P(Y)$?

It can be shown that depending on the form of $P(X)$ in the limit $X\to\inf$, the form of $P(Y)$ changes. If $P(X)$ decays as a power-law for $X\to\inf$, then $P(Y)$ is a Frechet distribution. If there's a finite end-point $x_0$ which is approached as $(x_0-x)^\alpha$, then it follows a Weibull distribution, whose parameters can be easily written as a function of the sample size $n$. If $P(X)$ decays faster than a power-law, then $P(Y)$ is a Gumbel distribution (I'm not sure one can write its parameters as a function of $n$ as in the case of the Weibull). This is important because it shows universal behavior, i.e. details don't matter so it's the same for $e^{-x}$, $e^{-x^2}$ or any other form. Only matters that it decays faster than a power-law. You can see it [in this book](https://books.google.es/books?id=rQSIZVOQfWYC&pg=PA1&hl=es#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 24. Also, note that the discussion here for maximums also applies to minimums if we talk about the properties of the left tail of $P(X)$ instead of its right tail.

However, these results are only valid in the limit of an infinite sample size. If you want to have the exact result for finite $n$, you will need to compute by yourself the form of $P(Y)$ for the specific distribution $P(X)$, as shown e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32353).